# How to cast an Object Reference in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: casting, default-value, unreal-engine4, object-reference, unreal-blueprint

I want to reference an asset from another Blueprint to trigger an event from that.

I have a variable with Object Reference type, and I set its default value to the particular asset I'm interested in.

When it comes to action, I call a Cast node with the variable as an input, but the casting always fails. I cannot understand it at all, because I thought that due to the default value it is already in the correct type.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are some image of the problem:

[image]
[image]

The OnMessageReceived event is triggered correctly, then I see the second ("Unsuccessful cast...") message on screen.

Comment: What do you get when you print the display name of `Sedane`?

Comment: I get what I expect: "Sedane_BP_child"

Comment: Should work. Problem may be in a part of the project you have not shown.

Comment: Which part of the project would help you find out the answer?

Comment: The part with the problem of course! (If I knew that then I'd also know the problem). Perhaps you have two different blueprints named `Sedane_BP_child`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution. The problem was not with the casting but with the place of setting it's default value.

I moved that part to the level blueprint and now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately the context is not very clear. but i don't think casting works in this case. Try with:

[One Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmMJ8.jpg)
[More items in Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZTlf.jpg)